# counting the number of unique values that exist as opposite pairs in two columns within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, userid

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows of user interaction data.

I used this to give me only users who's userID starts with certain letters

```
df[
df.userA.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5')) &
df.userB.str.startswith(('b','c','e','f','5'))
]
```

Which returned something that looks like this

```
   userA column:                           userB column:                           timestamp column: 
   f55570ac-c757-4e1f-b0b2-34997614f929    5ccd7ffd-7776-4a81-81dd-5331972454c2   2017-12-12 00:00:00
   5bfb4313-1d38-4dd2-944d-82bcabea9e31    ebc48322-f8b8-4994-968c-93e8d9e9df1d   2017-12-13 00:03:00
   ebc48322-f8b8-4994-968c-93e8d9e9df1d    5bfb4313-1d38-4dd2-944d-82bcabea9e31   2017-12-14 00:03:00
```

What this "shows" is that in the first row, user f55570ac- followed user 5ccdffd at at that timestamp.

In the second row, user 5bfb4313- followed ebc48322- at that time stamp, and in the third row, user ebc48322- followed user 5bfb4313- back at that timestamp, and thus have a **mutual relationship**.

**How do I count the number of *mutual relationships*  within the entire dataframe? I.e., the pairs of *unique userID's* that exist in userA column and userB column?**

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just check the colA values in colB ,you can use this snippet

```
df['userA column: '].isin(df['userB column: ']).sum()
```

Out:

```
2
```

Finding Sequence of occurrences count in userA and userB

```
pd.concat([df['userA']+'->'+df['userB'],df['userB']+'->'+df['userA']]).value_counts()
```

Out:

```
5bfb4313-1d38-4dd2-944d-82bcabea9e31->ebc48322-f8b8-4994-968c-93e8d9e9df1d    2
ebc48322-f8b8-4994-968c-93e8d9e9df1d->5bfb4313-1d38-4dd2-944d-82bcabea9e31    2
5ccd7ffd-7776-4a81-81dd-5331972454c2->f55570ac-c757-4e1f-b0b2-34997614f929    1
f55570ac-c757-4e1f-b0b2-34997614f929->5ccd7ffd-7776-4a81-81dd-5331972454c2    1
```

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3062             try:
-> 3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:



KeyError: 'userA: '

Comment: I should add the name of the coumns are "userA" and "userB" (not "userA column" "useB coulumn")

Comment: when i run df['userA: '].isin(df['userB: ']).sum() i get that error pointing to userA

Comment: please check the column names and give proper column names in place of column df["'    "]        (df.columns will give proper name of column) @EricMyhre

Comment: df.columns returns Index(['userA', 'userB', 'timestamp'], dtype='object'). When i run df['userA: '].isin(df['userB: ']).sum()  I still get the above error. @nagakiran

Comment: plz use df['userA'].isin(df['userB']).sum()  . it will work :-)

Comment: bless your soul @NagaKiran

Comment: @NagaKiran so i have a problem: this method only counts the number of times userA appears in userB. It does not account for the the fact that other users could follow the same person. In our example, we counted 2 times that someone from userA appeared in userB, but that was only an example of 1 "mutual relationship". Someone from userA could appear in userB, but that doesn't mean the person from userB corresponds to that 'mutual relationship'. What I'm trying to do is count the number of people that follow each other... Another road block :-(

Comment: to clarify: I define a mutual relationship as unique user from userA -> unique user from userB and that same unique user from userB -> that same unique user from userB, and then count the number of times those types of relationships appear

Comment: Hi @EricMyhre , is it related to count of sequence of occurances of A->B and B->A w.r.t users ?

Comment: @NagaKiran Yes.

Comment: Hi @EricMyhre i just edited code in retrieving count of sequence occurances, is it something you want ?

Comment: @NagaKiran yes, that would be great